# Jquery click only works with double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I am so close to getting this.  Here's my code that is returning the correct url, but only when button is double-clicked.  I only need one click to retrieve the image.

```
 var origin = 'COMP';
 var area = 'US';
 var type = 'typeA';
 var level = 'Xnay';
 var time = '0';
 var btn1 = document.getElementById("redbutton").winControl;   

function change_area(new_area) {
     area = new_area;
}

function change_type(new_type) {
     type = new_type;
}      

$(btn1).click(function () {
  var src = "http://somesite.net/folder/WEB_" + origin + "_" + area + "_" + level + "_" + type + "_" + time + "HR.png";
         change_area('GB');
         change_type('typeB')
         $('#mainmap').attr('src', src), false;
});
```

Comment: did you find what happens in console when u clik the first time

Comment: How do I view this?  I have the javascript console visible during debug but I cannot see each process/click.

Answer (score 0):

You try by adding

`$(document).ready(function() { });` block

before the following line

```
$(btn1).click(function () {
```

Finally as,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(btn1).click(function () {
         var src = "http://somesite.net/folder/WEB_" + origin + "_" + area + "_" + level + "_" + type + "_" + time + "HR.png";
         change_area('GB');
         change_type('typeB')
         $('#mainmap').attr('src', src), false;
    });
});
```